# Pixels Per Unit for unity sprite not aligning the correct amount of pixels

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

This might be a simple question, but I'm having trouble with the pixel per unit setting in unity. As you can see in this picture, I have a sprite that is about 1000 pixels tall, and the ppu is set to 100, but the sprite is only taking up about 3 units. Shouldn't it take up ten units?

[image]

Is there another setting I have turned on? Or am I just misunderstanding how ppu works?
The sprite image is a png if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already found the answer, just for others with the same problem:
You have to set the filter mode from "Bilinear" to "Point(No Filter)"